# Another weird word search? What is this cat burglar up to?

Tags: steganography, word-search

Remember [our favorite cat burglar from last time](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/103950/a-weird-sort-of-word-search-cat-burglar)? Yeah, they’re back. This time, they left *this* not-so-standard word search puzzle behind. I found this in the newspaper and wanted to share it with some Puzzlers to see if they would be interested in helping out the police.

```
u v l d t c q 3 b h j f x t n 
b o q a 7 y z r t e 4 i f i o 
d c u c u 8 b e n y a p p w y 
u i a p w e e g e s n j v h v 
c n t t i x m h y t d e e m u 
w o n k k q i g 2 v 3 v m e a 
u a i f a i i o l s v p d l j 
v d r h p d f p g a z c p q k 
a k z j m j z w t i g t c n e 
v o g t w l x b m k y s n m i 
v m u f c h z v w k k n d z e 
h y i q i v z d y x h x r n a 
j v c r j u e l f i w z i 5 e 
v l 9 f a m g e y t 4 r p 8 t 
t y d v a 4 s k m h o r 1 o f
```

What’s the deal this time? This time, the police have upped the reward to $0.21, so there’s a greater incentive!

---

Hint 0:

> Think about different *types* of letters.

Hint 1:

> Again, not all letters are significant. Think of all the different characters in this word search!

Hint 2:

> Hint 0 is referring to `_ow___` and `c_____a___`. After that, think about the numbers.

Hint 3:

> Think about numbers after the `v_____` and `co____an__`. It's all about positioning!

---

I will post an answer on Oct 27 if nothing has happened.

Comment: $0.21? What an increase!

Comment: @TrojanByAccident -- It's all about the money!

Comment: To clarify, only the puzzle is important, and the rest is fluff, correct?

Comment: @TrojanByAccident -- Yep, exactly right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is...

> land on my feet,

which is also

> something cats are known for!

Here's how you get it:

> Look at the grid and find the numbers:
>  [image: numbers highlighted]

Next,

> Look at the letters *before* the numbers:
>  [image: letters before numbers]

Notice

> The vowels and consonants refer to whether you look at the row the number is in or its column. There then become two possibilities for answers.
>  [image: possibility 1]
>
>  OR
>
>  [image: possibility 2]

The first option gives:

> LANDONMYFEET

And the second one gives:

> EZAETA...

So, clearly, the answer is:

> land on my feet.

I understand that the puzzle may have been very difficult without the hints, but that's sort of the point. It wasn't totally impossible! Also note that Hint 0 was given with the puzzle in the beginning and Hint 1 followed very shortly after.

Comment: There are many, many similar things that could be done - how were people expected to figure out what particular method you wanted without reading your mind? (For instance, you could swap the meaning of vowels and consonants, or use letters with ascenders versus letters without; you could look after the numbers instead of before; you could look *n* letters back for a number *n*, instead of just using the first letter back; you could use (x,y) coordinates instead of (row,col); you could use the numbers as offsets ("move this many letters") instead of coordinates...)